# Creating a field for Account Team Members

Tags: dashboard, filters, account-teams

Does anyone know of a way where I can get all of the account team members into a custom field on the account page. So if John Doe and Jane Doe were on Account ABC, is there a way I can get those names into a custom field called Account Team? My end goal is to be able to filter the field on the dashboards. Thanks!

Comment: Once this field is populated it still might not do what you need. E.g. "Jane Doe,John Doe", you couldn't do a filter for "Jane Doe" since dashboard filters don't let you do contains (at least last I'd checked).

Comment: Might be good to update your question with what you're trying to accomplish with the dashboard, might help get some more out of the box ideas for how to address your core need.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to write code to do this, however, you can't put a trigger on the Account Team Member object so this would be tricky.

One solution might be a Scheduled batch that rolls through your Accounts and Account Team Members on a schedule and concatenates their names into a field.

You could also add a trigger on to the Account that queries the Account Team Members and adds them to the field but adding/editing/removing Account Team Members wouldn't invoke that trigger. You'd have scenarios where the field wasn't updated until the next DML operation (save) on the Account.

You should vote for this -> [Allow triggers on Account Team Member Object](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YR8IAAW)

Answer (score 0):

> Apart from Batch solution suggested ,You can build an Inline Visualforce to Add Account Team Member and getting rid of Standard one and that would allow to update the Parent Account fields as well.
>
> If you are thinking of out of box report would recommend double checking as show filter on reports has Account Team Members I believe and you can use that report to build dashboard